# Перестал работать PjAX .Yii2

Tags: yii2, pjax

Здравствуйте, у меня небольшая проблемка возникла. Я решил сделать , чтобы можно было вводить дату в форму с помощью виджета Jquery datepicker . Получилось реализовать, но после этого перестал работать PJAX (информация добавляется и удаляется , но теперь с подгрузкой страницы. Если вам не сложно, помогите разобраться . Вот мой код

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'date')->widget(\yii\jui\DatePicker::class, [
            'language' => 'ru',
            'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',

        ]) ?> 
<?php Pjax::begin(['id'=>'salaryGrid', 'enablePushState' => false]); ?>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],


            ['attribute'=>'worker_id_f','value'=>function($model){return $model->workerIdF->full_name;},'filter'=>app\models\Worker::getWorkerList()],
            'premium',
            'fine',
            'date',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'template'=>'{delete}',
                'buttons' => [
                    'delete' => function ($url) {
                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', '#', [
                            'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'Delete'),
                            'aria-label' => Yii::t('yii', 'Delete'),
                            'onclick' => "
                                if (confirm('Вы уверены,что хотите удалить запись?')) {
                                    $.ajax('$url', {
                                        type: 'POST'
                                    }).done(function(data) {
                                        $.pjax.reload({container: '#salaryGrid'});
                                    });
                                }
                                return false;
                            ",
                        ]);
                    },



                ],],
        ],
    ]); ?>
    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
<?php $script=<<< JS
$('form#{$model->formName()}').on('beforeSubmit',function(e) {

    var \$form=$(this);
    $.post(\$form.attr("action"),\$form.serialize())
    .done(function(result){
                $(\$form).trigger("reset");
                $.pjax.reload({container:'#salaryGrid'});


           })
            .fail(function() {
              console.log("server error");
            })
    return false;
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

Comment: Добрый вечер. Посмотрите, для начала, ошибки js в консоли браузера.

Comment: Ошибок никаких не пишет.Оно удаляет, добавляет- без проблем, но ajax обновления странички не происходит. Ajax запрос  проходит с 200 кодом.